# htaccess returning 404 page not found

Tags: .htaccess

I am getting 404 page not found due to htaccess.
This is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule category/^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ college.php?category=$1
```

I want url to be created like

```
college.php?category=(some text)
```

Comment: Could you please do let us know if your .htaccess rules file and college.php files are in same path?

Comment: Yes both are on same path

Comment: ok, could you please do mention complete paths of both the files here?